# Monitor passing requests to WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to make a ripper for a very specific video, problem is that the video is called with an URL called out of a Silverlight player. If I open the page with Firefox + Firebug I can see on the NET tab the URL of the movie coming by.

Now I want to intercept the same results only in my own C# application, is this possible? I have tried the webbrowser control but it does not really have these kind of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put FiddlerCore within your application.

http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore